# Association object handling, appending children to parent, concealing the usage of a “middle” table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-admin

I'm looking for convenient way to create ModelView, used to append a number of children to a parent when creating it.
For example, I've got models:

```
class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'order'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    things = db.relationship('OrderList', back_populates='order', lazy='dynamic')

class OrderList(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'order_list'
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('order.id'), primary_key=True)
    thing_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('things.id'), primary_key=True)
    amount = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=10, scale=3))
    order = db.relationship('Order', back_populates='things', lazy='joined')
    thing = db.relationship('Thing', back_populates='orders', lazy='joined')

class Thing(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    orders = db.relationship('OrderList', back_populates='thing', lazy='dynamic')
    stock = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=10, scale=3))
    price = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=10, scale=3))
```

Simply adding that models to flask-admin, I would get an opportunity to append OrderList instances to Thing or to Order:

[image]
[image]
But how do I append children to parent without accessing middle OrderList object? Just like using One-to-many relationship.

Table scheme:

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to append `Thing` to `Order`  , you haven't defined any relationship there. I might be mistaken , can you explain the question in little more detail.

Comment: @Siddhant Why did you assume I haven't defined any relationship? Actually, I've used db.relationship to relate Order to OrderList and OrderList to Thing to declare M-to-M relationship. I'll extend my question with table scheme.

Answer (score 1):

From what I am understanding , you want to define a many to many relationship on `Order` and `Thing` .

Rather than declaring `OrderList` class , I think you should declare the many to many relation like this

1. [Many to Many](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/models/#many-to-many-relationships)
2. [Adding Removing in MtM](http://techarena51.com/index.php/many-to-many-relationships-with-flask-sqlalchemy/)

This way you can create instances of both `Order` and `Thing` and add them to each other to create a Many to Many relationship.

**EDIT**

You can use [Association Proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects) to get the work done.

You need to add the following constructor to your`OrderList class`

```
def __init__(self,amount, order, thing):
    self.amount = amount
    self.order = order
    self.thing = thing
```

Other than this you will have to define `association proxy` as shown in the link. This should get your work done.

Comment: As you can see above, I've already defined MtM relationship using `Assotiation Object` pattern - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object
I can't use basic `association_table` pattern since i need store additional data, like `price` and `amount`. Now I need to make flask-admin to allow appending children (things) to parrent (order) while creating a new one without bothering with proxy object.

Comment: ok, supposing i've done with OrderList class, AssotioationProxy and others, how do I now set amount and price of every thing while creating new order? I need to extend default order edit view with additional fields at least.

Comment: Please check the documentation link I have provided in my answer. It has been explained there.

Comment: It isn't a problem to append children to a parent using python+sqlalchemy+(optional)AssotiationProxy for me, but problem is to show and then handle List of Fields when creating new parent. Suppose I create new parent, choice a number of children, then i want to describe a number of children through list of field appeared somewhere below. This list looks like (child 1 - price - amount, child 2 - price - amount etc)